# failed to retrieve object value inside IONIC ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i try to write a simple code on `view` like

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="optJawab" ng-value="'blabla'" id="blabla"><label for="blabla">blabla</label>
```

and i succeeded to retrieve at console

```
console.log(this.optJawab);
```

and i facing problem with `ng-repeat`, console on controller said **undefined**?
code like below.

```
<div class="divTable" ng-repeat="quest in Questions track by $index">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="optJawab[$index]" ng-value="'blabla'" id="blabla">
    <label for="blabla">blabla</label>
</div>
```

Comment: ok so you want your model to be fetched from array Questions??

Comment: yess and be able to read from my controller

Comment: post your json here

Comment: http://play.ionic.io/app/640d97a0ca36 please review

Answer (score 0):

change like this,

```
console.log($scope.optJawab);
```

Comment: still undefined :(

Comment: can you create a plunker? because no idea how you have assigned those values

Comment: i have to create plunker account and i don't know how to start with ionic packages on there.

Comment: http://play.ionic.io/app/640d97a0ca36 updated.. and still need your help

Comment: i dont find anywhere this variable in your code optJawab

Comment: i need optJawab on alert in controller $scope.klikBerikutnya = function() {
 
  alert('test');

 }

Comment: @MrBoJangles what do you mean?

Comment: I was a bit hasty in adding that comment. I removed it.